# Chinese remainder theorem for composition

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, fields

Let $f(x) \in F_p[x]$ and I know $f(x)$ modulo two polynomials $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$.  What sort of information about $f$ modulo the composition $\phi_1(\phi_2(x))$ can I recover?

I'm looking for a Chinese remainder theorem for the composition.

Degree considerations on $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$ reveal that it is impossible to fully recover $f(x)$ but I'm wondering if there are any intermediate results.

Comment: Think of it this way: knowing $f$ mod $\phi$ essentially means knowing the values of $f$ on the roots of $\phi$ (in an algebraic closure). It seems unlikely you can say anything interesting about the values of $f$ on the roots of $\phi_1\circ\phi_2$ from its values on the roots of $\phi_1$ and of $\phi_2$. Now maybe if you were to ask about $f\circ\phi_2$, of if this were about some different kind of “modulo” or by changing the question in other ways there might be something to say — I don't know.

Comment: To be concrete, its like I know how $f$ behaves with $x^2+1$ and $x^3+1$ and I just want to figure out how it behaves with $(x^2+1)^3+1$. Playing around with the system of equations gives some information. In this case (with degrees 2 and 3), I should be able to narrow down $f$ to one of $p$ elements in $F_{p^6}$

Comment: "Narrow down $f$ to one of $p$ elements in $F_{p^6}$." So, you are viewing a polynomial $f$ as an element of the field of $p^6$ elements?

Answer (score 3):

Knowing $f$ modulo $x^2+1$ and $x^3+1$ is equivalent to knowing $x$ modulo $\operatorname{lcm} (x^2+1,x^3+1)$, i.e. $(x^2+1) (x^3+1)$ unless $p=2$ in which case it is $(x+1)(x+1)^3$.

So the ordinary chinese remainder theorem implies that $f$ modulo $(x^2+1)^3+1$ is completely free except that $f$ modulo $$\operatorname{gcd} ( (x^2+1)(x^3+1), (x^2+1)^3+1) = \operatorname{gcd} ( (x^3+1), (x^2+1)^3+1)$$ (since $x^2+1$ is relatively prime to $(x^2+1)^3+1$ in every characteristic) is completely determined.

We have $(x^2+1)^3+1 = x^6 + 3x^4 + 3x^2 +2$ and dividing by $x^3+1$ gives remainder $ 3x^2 - 3x + 3$ so in characteristic $3$ this gcd is $(x^3+1)$ and in every other characteristic it is $x^2-x+1$.

So for $p$ not $3$, we see that $f$ is determined modulo $x^2-x+1$ and otherwise $f$ modulo $(x^2+1)^3+1$ is completely free.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for the example. I'm still looking for general results though about $f$ modulo compositions.

Comment: I have some trouble parsing the sentence "completely free except that $f$ modulo …" at the end of the second paragraph.  What is the claim about the residue?  (There's an equals sign, but that seems just to be saying that two $\gcd$s are equal.  Incidentally, on that note, `\gcd` is pre-defined, and need not be `\operatorname`d, though of course it's harmless.)

Comment: @LSpice It was missing a few words, fixed, though it may still be a bit unclear.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452560/chinese-remainder-theorem-for-composition/452572#comment1170437_452572), thanks.  It is clear to me now.